# Parameter 'login_failure_type ' not returned for Login event in Reports API

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I am trying to find the login_failure_type for a login_failure event using the G Suite Admin SDK Reports API (reference: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/activity/login?#login_failure). For all events I pull through this request, the login_type and login_challenge_method paremeters are included, but the login_failure_type parameter is omitted.

Does the login_failure_type parameter require an extra request parameter to get back or is this parameter no longer available?

Comment: Could you include the response in your post?